# How to debug "Missing Font" in Google Chrome (added by Chrome Extension)

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fonts

**TL;DR: Is it possible to view the *available* fonts on a website (Chrome)?**

I use Chrome OS, which doesn't allow you to install custom fonts on the system.

To workaround that, I created a chrome extension that adds the fonts that I want to web pages:

```json
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"], 
      "css" : ["fonts.css"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
        "resources": ["fonts/*.ttf", "fonts/*.woff2"],
        "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
    }
  ]
```

And the CSS just defines the font-face:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Hack';
  src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/hack-regular.woff2');
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}

code { font-family: 'Hack', monospace !important; }
pre { font-family: 'Hack', monospace !important; }
:root { --monospace-font-family: 'Hack'; }
```

The last css rules are irrelevant (I think).

In general this worked well for sites similar to vscode-remote, which let me pick the font in the settings. However, I found one internal site from my company that doesn't let me do that.

I see the computed css, which specifies my font, but apparently it is not found:

```css
font-family: Hack, "Comic Sans MS", monospace;
```

I also see that the css rules get applied by an "injected stylesheet" (but I can't debug that stylesheet because it comes from an extension.

Basically, I have my font working on other website. I have my css being installed, I have my font being used, **why is it not loading?**.

I checked the network tab and it is not being downloaded even (as it is in other websites).

Comment: One idea that I had was that _maybe_ this specific website didn't have access to the font resources, so I changed the font-face to point to a public URL. I tried it on a regular website and it worked, but it still didn't work on this particular website. No network request or anything.

Comment: IIRC there's a bug in chrome extension's handling of fonts from web_accessible_resurces, so people either put their entire UI inside a web_accessible_resurces `iframe` or use a data: URL for the font.

Comment: Do you have more info about that? It works for me, but maybe because I am not doing anything too complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you need to install the font on [all frames](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#frames).

The updated `manifest.json`:

```json
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"], 
      "all_frames": true,
      "css" : ["fonts.css"]
    }
  ],
```

A coworker hinted at the issue, and I confirmed it when I tried to use a font that was added to a parent iframe and not to the one that I wanted.

As for "How to debug" these kinds of issues, that still doesn't have a clear answer. I could not find a way to list which fonts were available for a given frame, nor to see whether the injected CSS was installed on that frame.